# Taking in uppercase and lower case alphabet character

Tags: java, boolean, uppercase

I am trying to figure out how I can accept user input in both upper and lowercase letters in the code below. My application takes in a string of the user's name and I need to be able to let them know if the character is in there regardless of capitalization.

```
boolean p=str.contains("R");
if(p)
System.out.println("string contains the char 'R'");
else
System.out.println("string does not contains the char 'R'");
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simple convert your input by invoking [`toUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--) which will return a string in all upper case letters and then apply `contains` on the returned type

```
boolean p = str                // robot
               .toUpperCase()  // ROBOT
               .contains("R"); // ROBOT contains R? true/false
// note: value of str is still robot as original
```

although if you don't need `p` more than once then no need to perform another character check then

```
if(str.toUpperCase().contains("R"))
    System.out.println("string contains the char 'R'");
else
    System.out.println("string does not contains the char 'R'");
```

Comment: That seems to work, but I need to account for lowercase and uppercase letters - so if the user entered Maurice Moss and the selected character was m, it should indicate that the character was found. and I'm wondering if I can use something in the program to randomly pick a character between a and z. possibly the Math.random() function?

Comment: @RobNelson if only one input is coming from user either the string or the character then choose a standard (upper or lower) for the value of yours and convert the user input accordingly,or  if both input are dynamic then use `if(str.toUpperCase().contains(someStringchar.toUpperCase()))`, to uppercase is a method od string class so can be invoked on any string object (represented by "some string") or string class

Comment: Thank you both, I replaced str.toUpperCase() to str.toLowercaseCase(). The code will now look for both capital and lowercase letters! thanks for your help.

Comment: i am glad that i could help, happy coding!

Comment: Please note that only using `toUpperCase` is not sufficient in some cases. That's why `equalsIgnoreCase()` does both `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase`

Comment: @ACV please note, OP just wants to check the existence of one char in a string